# Setting Gimp's "Page Setup" dialog to units other than inches

Tags: gimp

Is it possible to set Gimp's`Page Setup` dialog to units other than inches? I have an image set to millimeter units, I have everything I can see set to millimeters, but when I select `File->Page Setup` to create a custom page size, the only option I have is inches.

I'm running on Ubuntu with Gimp 2.6.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible right now, and that is a bug on the application.

When you find issues like that, you can help further the tool development by filling up a bug report at http://bugs.gnome.org

I know it may seems just "huh?" how can this be unnoticed - the fact is that many open soruce tools, GIMP included are written on developer's spare times and I can tell you most actie GIMP developers don't use it for printing at all - therefore, the printing side of the tool is getting little attention.

Comment: Thanks kindly. I've submitted a bug report now: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652806